# "I need more" - is "more" a noun or an adverb?

Tags: pronouns, fused-determiner

> 1. There's More to Life Than This
> 2. I Need More.

What do you think about the word "more" in these two sentences ?  1 look like noun and 2  adverb to me.

Comment: "More" means here what the dictionary definition mentions. What is your question, by the way?

Comment: It's a pronoun; see the examples [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/more).

Answer (score 3):

In both, *more* is employed as a pronoun.

It cannot be an adverb in 2, because that would leave *need* without its obligatory Direct Object. *More* has to be a pronoun.

ADDED:
*Pronoun* is the category assigned in traditional grammars. A modernist approach  treats *more* as a *determinative* quantifier like *some*, *all*, *many* and understands the uses here as *fused determiners*: that is, the word "fuses" with the noun it modifies:

> I need more (something) → I need more.